# How can I select a table that have 2 part name(Mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

I know this question is a little stupid. But I will appreciate to answer it,
I have a table, The table have 2 part name. for example the name is "My Table" with one Space between "my" and "Table".
I used select * from dbo.{My Table} in MS SQL server. 
But I cannot use it in mysql.
Is there any other syntax to retrieve information from these tables like "My Table" ?
Thanks

Comment: In MySQL, the escape character is a backtick, so `\`My Table\``.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use backtick

```
 SELECT * FROM `Your Table`
```

Answer (score 1):

I'll refer you to a couple of pages from the MySQL manual:

- [Schema Object Names](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/identifiers.html)
- [Identifier Qualifiers](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/identifier-qualifiers.html)

I'm posting these links instead of the answer deliberately. You should learn to answer these sorts of questions by familiarizing yourself with the documentation.